# Session Management in servicestack

Tags: servicestack

In the Icenium Hybrid app we have a requirement like we need to keep the logged in user's session active for about 8 hours and then log-out automatically.

The app is connecting to the Servicestack REST services which also handles sessions at the server side.

How do we handle the session management on the device as well as server side?Any examples are highly appreciated.